# Paste range side by side in email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word, copy-paste

the code below paste two range in an email body one after the other, how to modify the code so the two range are pasted next to each other `rng` on the left and `rng2` on the right

**update: managed to get the range side by side using a table with 1 row and 2 columns as suggested by Tim in the comments, problem now is it is too far apart would like to know how to make the pasted ranges closer to each other**

**update 2: decided to create a table with 3 rows and 2 columns and copy paste each range into each cell, but still the same problem the cells width are too wide using `wordTbl.AllowAutoFit = True` does not resize the cell width**

**UPDATE 3 SOLVED WITH `wordTbl.Columns(1).AutoFit`**

```
Sub sendRange()
Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long, x
Dim j As Long: j = 1
Dim k As Long: k = 1
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rngTable, xCell As Range
Dim doc As Object, wordTbl As Object

For i = 3 To lastRow Step 3
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display '.Send

        .Body = "There it was" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        Set rngTable = doc.Range
        rngTable.Collapse Direction:=0
        Set wordTbl = doc.Tables.Add(rngTable, 3, 2)
        
        Set rng = sht.Range("A" & i & ":A" & i + 2)
        Set rng2 = sht.Range("Q" & i & ":Q" & i + 2)
        
        For Each xCell In rng
                xCell.Copy
                wordTbl.cell(j, 1).Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
                j = j + 1
        Next xCell
        
        For Each xCell In rng2
                xCell.Copy
                wordTbl.cell(k, 2).Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
                k = k + 1
        Next xCell

        .to = sht.Range("S" & i + 2)
        .Subject = "Here it is"
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: One fairly obvious solution would be to copy the two ranges next to each other in a hidden sheet, then select the pair of ranges and copy/paste to your email.

Comment: Create a two-cell table and paste each range into one of the cells?

Comment: @TimWilliams did as you suggested, would it be possible to get the desired output above?

Comment: You could either set the horizontal alignment (https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.word.vba.beginners/c/ONlpe0j1Z2Q) or size the table you added so it just fits the pasted content.

Comment: Consider rolling back at least the last edit and posting an answer. You could accept if there are no better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code below solves my problem but  still open to someone offering a better solution

nitpicking the code below does not copy the interior color format of the copied cell

```
Sub sendRange()
Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long, x
Dim j As Long: j = 1
Dim k As Long: k = 1
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rngTable, xCell As Range
Dim doc As Object, wordTbl As Object

For i = 3 To lastRow Step 3
    With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .Display '.Send

        .Body = "There it was" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        Set doc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        Set rngTable = doc.Range
        rngTable.Collapse Direction:=0
        Set wordTbl = doc.Tables.Add(rngTable, 3, 2)
        
        Set rng = sht.Range("A" & i & ":A" & i + 2)
        Set rng2 = sht.Range("Q" & i & ":Q" & i + 2)
        
        For Each xCell In rng
                xCell.Copy
                wordTbl.cell(j, 1).Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
                j = j + 1
        Next xCell
        
        For Each xCell In rng2
                xCell.Copy
                wordTbl.cell(k, 2).Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
                k = k + 1
        Next xCell
        
        wordTbl.Columns(1).AutoFit
        wordTbl.Columns(2).AutoFit

        .to = sht.Range("S" & i + 2)
        .Subject = "Here it is"
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```